# Absence of anti-Stokes line in Raman spectrum

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy, raman

> If we have a molecule 1H-25X which shows a band at $3000~\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$ in the IR spectrum and you want to record a Stokes and anti-Stokes Raman spectrum with a laser of 1000 nm, why is the anti-Stokes band not observed?

My guess is that if you would calculate the wavelength of the anti-Stokes line, then you would get 769 nm. In this region there might be fluorescence, which could interfere with the spectrum. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Hi Fechem, welcome to Chemistry! Take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Regular text can be formatted with [Markdown](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), and mathematical expressions and chemical equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: Consider the size of the vibrational quantum vs thermal energy of $\approx 210 \mathrm{cm}^{-1}$ at room temperature. Not many molecules are going to be excited in $v=1$; you can work out the fraction $\approx \exp(-3000/210)$.  Excitation at 1 micron will probably not excite an electronic state as this energy is so low, so no fluorescence, but of course this will depend on exactly what the molecule is.